# Is there a custom domain plugin

Tags: wordpress

It there an plugin or a way to have two domains on one WordPress (website) installation.
Without having a multi site installation?

For example
domain1.com
domain2.com
This is the same website, only another url

/Daan

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress store absolute urls in DB.
Seems like it`s impossible without multi site.